# Drag in drop - VueJs + laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js, drag-and-drop, draggable

I have an application in Vuejs + laravel. I need to implement a drag in drop so i can drag a name from a list and drop it on an input, when I drop it on this input it returns other data, address, nationality, birthday...

My code:

List:

```
<div class="card-body">

            <div v-for="(cliente, index) in clientes" :key="index">
              <span @click="toggleItem" style="cursor: pointer;"> <i class="far fa-building"></i>{{cliente.nome}}</span>
              <div>
                <div v-for="(obra, index) in cliente.obras" :key="index" style="margin-left: 20px;">
                  <span v-show="toggled" draggable="true" @dragstart="onDragging" :id="obra.id"> <i class="far fa-user"></i>{{ obra.nome }} - {{ obra.cidade }}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

field to drop the item:

```
<div id="box-droppable" @drop="drop" @dragover="allowDrop">
  <h3>Droppable area:</h3>
  <hr>
</div>
```

My methods:

```
methods: {

      onDragging(ev){
        ev.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = "copy";
        console.log(ev);
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
      },

      allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
      },

      drop(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "copy";
        ev.preventDefault();
        let data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        console.log(data);
      },

      toggleItem() {
        this.toggled = !this.toggled;
      },
```

Help, help me please. =D

Comment: My suggestion is too use the lifesaving package vue-draggable. https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable

Comment: The component works but is not effective in my application.